# Remove bronze/silver/gold tabs from the Badges page

Tags: feature-request, design, badges, responsive-design

On the [Badges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) you can switch between "color" of badges by selecting the corresponding tab (bronze/silver/gold) or by pressing the badge icon:

> [image]

Since the badge type info is always visible I suggest to remove the (bronze/silver/gold) tabs from this page. This could also fix little ugly formatting (page doesn't fit into screen horizontally) for mobile devices (when responsiveness is on) especially on localized sites like [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=all) where the text length is larger then on English based sites:

> [image]

Comment: I don't see those badge buttons, just the intro text and then the list.  Do you see it in both desktop and mobile views?

Comment: @MonicaCellio when responsiveness is off these buttons are located on the right hand side

Comment: Ah.  Or, more specifically, when the window is large enough to allow for it, those buttons are in the right column, where, on a desktop computer, I've never noticed them.

Comment: The advantage of having the tabs is it lets you narrow down your view to look at only one grade of badge. Maybe that should responsively disappear on sufficiently narrow screens, but if it's wide enough I don't think it's good to remove a feature like that.